# Reclassify by ASCII ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error, classification, reclassify, ascii

How do I create a ASCII remap if I want to reclassify values ranges such as the following:

0 - 200 > 5

201 - 400 > 10

etc..

[image: ASCII reclassification map]

I have tried it but it gives me this error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the Esri help site [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-reclass-by-ascii-file-works.htm)

The following list provides some details on the correct formatting for the ASCII file:

> Comment lines can be entered beginning with the # symbol. There are no limits to the number of comments that can be entered.
>
> Each assignment line maps a value or range of values from the input raster to an output value. Only numeric values are accepted on an assignment line.
>
> All assignment lines in an ASCII remap file must be in the same format. Two formats are supported: one for reclassifying individually specified input values, the other for reclassifying ranges of input values.
>
> If a single value is to be reclassified to another value, the value is identified, followed by a space, a colon (:), another space, and the value to assign those cells on the output.

In addition, you are on the right path with your value setup

> Generically, the assignment line for a range of values appears as:
>
> in_min_value  in_max_value : out_value
>
> With values, it will appear as:
>
> 5 10 : 50

The issue appears to be in your range distribution because they mention here:

> **The input ranges of values should not overlap except at the boundary of two input ranges. When overlapping occurs, the higher end of the lower input range is inclusive, and the lower end of the higher input range is exclusive**; for example:
>
> 1 3 : 4   (where  1 <= value <= 3, values remapped to 4)
>   3 5 : 6   (where  3 <  value <= 5, values remapped to 6)
>   5 7 : 8   (where  5 <  value <= 7, values remapped to 8)

So you should change

0 - 200 > 5

201 - 400 > 10

etc..

to

0 - 200 > 5

200 - 400 > 10

Comment: I have already read what is in ArcGIS help before i posted the question but it gave me the error anyway.

Comment: So you changed your range as specified to 0 - 200 > 5 and 200 -400>10?

Comment: Yes I did change it

Comment: Did you receive the same error?

Comment: Yes I did receive the same error

Comment: Can you provide more information/screen shots of your raster attribute table. We will hopefully figure it out, however know we will look through all the files you are working with. Also, I would recommend starting a fresh session of ArcMap, create a new ASCII remap file as Esri states just to try one more time. In, the meanwhile provide more information about your files.